# PHP Variables with the same name

Tags: php, variables, phpbb

I am trying to integrate my login system made with PHP with the PHPBB Login system.
My problem is that I am including the PHP login document which contains a class called `$user` but my login system uses `$user` as well.
e.g My function for login is executing inside a class called $user and the phpbb login class is $user->login

Is it possible to load the phpbb document, and login in a separate kind of "environment" to my main website?

If you need any more info just let me know

Comment: By "environment" you mean scope. You should use classes for Facebook and for your login system, then you'll have $facebook->user, $login->user.

Comment: you've found a good reason to avoid global variables :)

Comment: can you show us the code thats causing the issue please.

Answer (score 3):

You could run your code in a function. Functions aren't passed global variables if you don't explicitly tell them ;)

Comment: A class cannot start with a `$`! You are dealing with an *instance* of a class and this instance may be created and used in another scope - function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not change the variable?

Such as

```
<?php
    include 'the/phpbb/core.pohp';

    $phpbb_user = $user;

    include 'my/login.pohp';

    if($user->valid_uid($phpbb_user->uid))
    {
    }
?>
```

---

edits:

Can you add a second variable

Open **common.php** and find the following:

```
$user  = new user();
```

add **After**

```
$backup_user  = $user;
```

Comment: you can create a static class to set/get objects, the static class would have a global scope for access but the objects stored inside them will be bound to the class scope.